# Code trying to find ServiceAccountCredential.cs file while accessing Google Analytics using OAUTH 2.0

Tags: c#, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to access Google Analytics data for `ga:visits` and `ga:transactions` using OAUTH 2.0 authentication. I have followed the following steps :

1. Enabled the Google Analytics API on the https://code.google.com/apis/console/ website.Also, created a client ID and saved the .p12 key
2. The generated email id was provided Read and Analyze access on Analytics website.
3. I have created a Windows form application and also downloaded the NuGet package using the package command:- Install-Package Google.Apis.Analytics.v3
   All the references including Google.Apis,Google.Apis.Analytics.v3,Google.Apis.Auth,Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices,Google.Apis.Core,Google.Apis.PlatformServices are added into the project

Further, while accessing the data am facing an error :-

> Locating source for
>   `c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\test\default\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\ServiceAccountCredential.cs`

while the following line of code is run :

```
var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new     ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)         
 {    
    Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly }    
 }.FromCertificate(cert));
```

Could you please help me with this error.
Please find below the code used :-

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.ComponentModel;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Drawing;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  
using Google.Apis.Analytics.v3;  
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;  
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;  
using Google.Apis.Services;  

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5  
{  
    public partial class Form1 : Form  
    {  
        public Form1()  
        {  
            InitializeComponent();  
        }  

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string keyFilePath = "C:\\Fetch GA Data-348e7435108b.p12";
            string serviceAccountEmail= "xx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";     
            string keyPassword = "notasecret";
            string websiteCode = "8482xxxx";     
            AnalyticsService service = null; 

            //loading the Key file     
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, keyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);  

            //Add Scopes
            var scopes =     
            new string[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics,AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsEdit,AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsManageUsers,AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly   
};       

            //create a new ServiceAccountCredential 
            var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)     
            {
                //Scopes = scopes     
                Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly }

            }.FromCertificate(cert));    

            //Create a Service
            service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()    
            {    
                HttpClientInitializer = credential    
            }); 


            DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest request = service.Data.Ga.Get(     
              "ga:" + websiteCode, "2015-05-27", "2015-05-27","ga:visits");     
            request.Dimensions = "ga:year,ga:month,ga:day";     
            var data = request.Execute();   

            }


        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you got that example from but its not even close to how you should be using a service account to access Google Analytics api.

```
 string[] scopes = 
          new string[] { 
             AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics,                 // view and manage your Google Analytics data
             AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsManageUsers};     // View Google Analytics data      

string keyFilePath = @"c:\file.p12" ;    // found in developer console
string serviceAccountEmail = "xx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";  // found in developer console
//loading the Key file
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential( new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                                                                  {
                                                                   Scopes = scopes
                                                                 }.FromCertificate(certificate));


AnalyticsService service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
             HttpClientInitializer = credential,
             ApplicationName = "Analytics API Sample",
            });
```

code ripped from [Google Analytics Authentication C#](http://www.daimto.com/googleanalytics-authentication-csharp/) tutorial series

**TIP Service Account Setup**

Take the service account email address from the Google Developer console, we need to give this email address access to our Google Analytics Data. We do that by adding it as we would any other user in the Admin Section of the Google Analytics Website. Add the service account email address as a user at the account level it must be the account level. This will enable your service account access to the Google Analytics account in question. Did I mention it must be at the ACCOUNT Level?

Comment: Hi.Thanks for your response.I have also writtent he code similar to your suggestion.Could you please have a look at the below.

Comment: @DalmTo :- I have improved my question and added my code which is similar to the one mentioned by you.However,it fails with the error when it tries to create ServiceAccountCredential.Could you please check and share your inputs.Thanks in advance.

Comment: check FromCertificate(cert));    whats cert?

Comment: did you check my tutorial there is a sample project on github you can download.

Comment: I did go through the sample project but am still getting the same error .I checked the value for cert and it shows cert is:-                          {[Subject]  CN=423234456098-7dnefrvrr80ie6kt1hse271if8bq9lnr.apps.googleusercontent.com[Issuer]  CN=423234456098-7dnefrvrr80ie6kt1hse271if8bq9lnr.apps.googleusercontent.com[Serial Number]  2D8A496E069713A9[Not Before]  6/24/2015 2:52:29 AM[Not After]  6/21/2025 2:52:29 AM[Thumbprint]  348E7435108B8A642DE356D3F63606435666ABFE}

Comment: I think you should try reinstalling the nuget package  if its not finding ServiceAccountCredential.cs there is something seriously wrong with your project.

Comment: I tried reinstalling the nuget package,as well as tried to set the .net framework version to 4.0 while using earlier versions of nuget packages.However,am still getting the same error. Any other suggestions/recommendations would be highly welcome.